# Ошибка правильных путей React для store

Tags: reactjs

Не могу подключить store к таблице, хотя указал правильный путь, что делать в таких ситуация?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Сам класс]

[image: Текст ошибки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому, что Вы попытались импортировать `Store` из файла `src/components/Table/*ваш-файл*`, компилятор TS делает следующие шаги:

1. Видит, что Вы пытаетесь импортировать что-то из `src/Store`;
2. Поскольку никаких переходов на предыдущие директории из разряда `..` у Вас нет, компилятор принимает `src/components/Table` как базу;
3. Он же пытается достучаться до файла `src/components/Table/src/Store`;
4. Такого файла у Вас не существует, следовательно, компилятор ругается таким образом, какой отображён у Вас в вопросе.

Чтобы задобрить товарища компилятора, нужно путь до файла прописать таким образом:

```
import Store from "../../Store"
```

Тогда план действий будет примерно таков:

1. Компилятор видит, что Вы поставили `../../`, следовательно, это команда ему идти на две папки вверх. Поскольку Ваш файл находится в папке `src/components/Table`, база теперь равна `src/`, т.е. мы "вышли" из подпапки `components` и подподпапки `Table`;
2. Теперь он стучится к `Store`, расположенной после данных инструкций;
3. В итоге получается, что мы ищем `Store` в пути `src/Store`;
4. По идее в данном пути есть класс `Store`, так что компилятор вместо ругательств спокойно импортирует класс куда надо :)

Как-то так.

P.S.: Если что, правила по перемещениям в командной строке (и не только) можно прочесть, например, [здесь](http://okiseleva.blogspot.com/2017/10/blog-post_59.html). Да, пример для CMD, но по сути работает и для TS, и для UNIX-подобных систем, и прочего :D